# How to update data in ngRepeat after successfully retrieving the JSON for custom url $http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Due to the fact that angularjs is not working with ngResource custom url, I have to try $http instead:

My html is something like:

```
//html
<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
  <td><a ng-click="changeGender(person)">{{person.gender}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

my idea is after clicking the anchor in the html, a request will be sent to the server and update, then send the status with 200 back and update the gender in the view. I build a service and it look like:

```
//factory
app.factory('changeGenderFactory', function($http, $q){
  return {
    getResult: function(person) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({method: 'POST', url: '/resources/people/' + person.id + '/gender'}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        deferred.reject(status);       
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

This is the controller:

```
//app
var app = angular.module('someApp', []);
//controller
app.controller('peopleCtrl', function($scope, ngResource, changeGenderFactory) {
  //skip how i get $scope.people...
  //$scope.people = ...(use ngResource)

  $scope.changeGender = function(person) {
    return changeGenderFactory.getResult(person);
  };
});
```

The ajax is working fine, but I guess something wrong with my controller part because the html is not updated at all. What should I do in order to update the data in ng-repeat in html? Thank you.

Comment: Your function changeGender does not seem to touch $scope.people at all so it would be very surprising if anything changed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I thought angular would bind this automatically. What should I do to update that particular row?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping Angular's $timeout service around your ngResource call inside your app.controller? I think what's happening here is your ng-repeater is referencing a $scope.people before the async request (your ngResource call) has returned. Therefore it is referencing undefined data that was returned synchronously in the form of a promise.

Comment: I tried to return the people object instead of just updating one row but no luck. I think alun is right because ngClick function is not binded to the data in the double curly brackets. I am still trying to find the way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I give up using ngResource and turning to $http and $q instead, ngResource doesn't completely suite in the case. Basically this is how I solve the issue:

In html:

```
{{changeGender(person, $index)}}
```

By passing an extra parameter $index, I can know which person in this case. Then in the controller:

```
$scope.changeGender = function(person, index) {
  //using $http, can move to service with $q, just for demo
  $http.post('someurl').success(function(data){
    $scope.people[index] = data;
  });
}
```

it might look clumsy but it is an alternative....